# Logging Bandwidth and Latency Metrics using GridDB: Sample Schema Request

Tags: sql, griddb

I'm developing a system to log and analyze ISP usage data using GridDB, and I'm looking for guidance on the most efficient way to store and retrieve the data. Can someone provide example code or best practices for implementing data logging in a GridDB database, particularly for recording metrics such as bandwidth usage, latency, and device connections?

```
import griddb_python

factory = griddb_python.StoreFactory.get_instance()
gridstore = factory.get_store(
    host="webserver",
    port=20001,
    cluster_name="ispcluster",
    username="admin",
    password="admin"
)
con_info = griddb_python.ContainerInfo("ISP_Usage_Data",
                                      [["timestamp", griddb_python.Type.TIMESTAMP],
                                       ["bandwidth", griddb_python.Type.DOUBLE],
                                       ["latency", griddb_python.Type.DOUBLE],
                                       ["device_id", griddb_python.Type.STRING]],
                                      griddb_python.ContainerType.TIME_SERIES)
ts = gridstore.put_container(con_info)


data = [
    (1636251600000, 100.5, 20.2, "device_1"),
    (1636251610000, 150.2, 15.8, "device_2"),
  
]

for entry in data:
    ts.put(entry)
```

I'm particularly interested in advice on schema design, indexing, and query optimization for scenarios involving frequent data inserts and efficient retrieval for analytical purposes. Any insights or sample code snippets would be greatly appreciated!